# Pushing two viewcontroller one after another does not localize backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am pushing two viewcontrollers one after another like below on a button press:

```
//Pushing first view controller    
    MyViewControllerOne *myViewControllerOne = [[MyViewControllerOne alloc] init];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"keyBack",nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewControllerOne animated:NO];

//Pushing Second view controller
    MyViewControllerTwo *myViewControllerTwo = [[MyViewControllerTwo alloc] init];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"keyBack",nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewControllerTwo animated:YES];
```

Now when I press the button , MyViewControllerTwo is shown, but with a back button title as "Back" and not the localized title that I have set for "keyBack" in Localizable.strings file, whereas when I push just only one viewcontroller in other parts of the code, it works fine and back button is shown in localized language.

How can I show the localized version of the backbarbutton?

Comment: By the way, why you need to so something this adventurous, like pushing 2 views back to back. I am convinced you can't see 2 view at once.

Comment: Because I need MyViewControllerOne when I press the back on MyViewControllerTwo, and back to the very first screen when I press back on MyViewControllerOne. I hope you get it what I imply here.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing more than one ViewController in to the navigation stack at once is bad practice.
I advise you find another way to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: So what is the other way out? I need to implement similar kind of functionality as described above.